# Slow login (first attempt) on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, login, dell, 22.04

I just installed Ubuntu 22.04 (before I had 20.04) on my Dell laptop and I am having issues with really slow login cca 10s.

Issue is appearing only on first attempt to login, whether it is successful or not, all attempts after the first are quick as I was used to cca 0.5s.

HW Info:

- Laptop model: Dell Inc. Latitude 5580
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7820HQ CPU @ 2.90GHz, 2900 MHz
- GPU: nVidia GM107 [GeForce 940MX], Intel HD Graphics 630
- Memory: 32,0 GiB

Answer (score 5):

Would have commented, but don't have the rep.

Check your log files for clues.

I noticed the same, with very slow logins taking more than 10 seconds.

In my case there was a problem with the nvidia driver. In `/var/log/gpu-manager-switch.log` there were many errors including `can't access /run/u-d-c-nvidia-drm-was-loaded file` and then a message saying it will take 10000ms for the nvidia udev rules to complete.

I upgraded my nvidia driver `sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-510` and now the error messages are gone and the logins are almost immediate.

Comment: I ran ```sudo apt-get install nvidia-driver-510``` and restarted my computer, after that I wasn't able to boot. To fix boot problem I had to enable SGX in BIOS and in recovery mode run commands from this answer  [NVIDIA-forum](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cant-boot-after-upgrading-to-510-driver-on-ubuntu-20-04/202625/8). After fixing boot problem I had problem with launching all of my snap applications (I had to reinstall them). 

At the end slow login issue was fixed, submitting of login is immediate but after that I have black screen for a few seconds, which is still not ideal.

Comment: Yes, it should be faster than that. Maybe try checking your log files for any strange errors or messages immediately after you log in.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this, and it turned out that it was happening because my monitor was plugged into the motherboard HDMI out rather than the GPU HDMI out.

After swapping the cable, the minutes-long hang after logging in disappeared.